ESP32 S3 video player (avi) using ESP processor instruction extensions (SIMD)
I want to create multi-task device useing ESP32-S3 module.
What I have:

ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1 (clone) N16R8 max frequency set (240MHz) [IDE: ESP-IDF]
DIY VGA (12-bit color mode) [probably will be expanded to 15-bit (5-bit per chanel)], output handled by custom VGA libruary based on bitluniVGA for ESP32-s3 [uses DMA buffer]
DIY SD Adapter (conected to ESP using 1-bit SDMMC mode 40MHz max)
USB Breakout

What I want to create:
Lua5.1 based operating system with AVI video player (programmed using C/C++) inside:
Stable 24-30 FPS video output (video: MJPEG/Cinepak; audio:PCM/MP3 [probably will be handled by vs1053 chip])
What I want to know: there are a lot of examples of video output BUT: ESP32-S3 has some  PIE (Processor Instruction Extensions) made for AI.
Those instructions are SIMD (single instruction, multiple data), and I am interested in using them to emulate some kind of pseudo GPU to optimise and speedup video decoding/output. If anyone who read this post know how to work with ESP32-s3 PIE SIMD, please tell me is that even possible? Can I decode MJPEG/Cinepak right into DMA buffer frame by frame using SIMD? If yes, then how.
Any help will be useful, guides/books/examples/links. I also need guides about ESP32-s3 assembler. I programmed in FASM before, but I don't thing ESP32 will accept it's code...
Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.
Some links I visited:
Basic video example: https://www.instructables.com/Play-AVI-With-ESP32/
PIE (Processor Instruction Extensions): https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf
Basic ESP32 SIMD minimal examples: https://bitbanksoftware.blogspot.com/2024/01/esp32-s3-simd-minimal-example.html
https://github.com/troyhacks/ESP32-S3_minimal_SIMD_example?ysclid=m3adtd0x4b857252057

P.S. I also would like to know: is it posible to encode only audio data from video, skipping visual content. I want my device to be able to play audio from YouTube videos.

FFmpeg / libavcodec has decoders for many common formats, many of them with hand-written asm for common ISAs like x86 with SSE2 (and some legacy MMX), and hopefully also ARM NEON.  If your CPU has NEON, you should be in good shape.  If it only has some new SIMD ISA intended specifically for AI, maybe not.
